How to avoid to refetch when the user press the back button
I display a list of posts in Razor Page using an embedded Blazor Server component.
Below is the index Razor Page code:
<component type="typeof(MyApp.Components.PostFeed)" render-mode="Server" />

Below is the PostFeed Blazor Component (reduced to bare minimum for simplicity):
@inject IPostRepo _repo

@foreach (var item in _items)
{
    <div>
        // Display Post Item ...
    </div>
}

@if (hasMore())
{
    <Button @onclick=fetchMore>More</Button>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Post> _items = default!;
    private int _page = 1;

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        _items = await _repo.Fetch(page: _page, pageSize: 5);
    }

    private bool hasMore() => _page < 10; // I fix page count to 10 for simplicity

    private async void fetchMore()
    {
        if (hasMore())
        {
            _page += 1;
            var newItems = await _repo.Fetch(page: _page, pageSize: 5);
            _items = _items!.Concat(newItems);

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}

My problem is that, let's say I click the more button to fetch the second page, then I open a post on the second page, bringing me to that post's razor page. Now when I click the back button on the phone or the browser to go back to the index, everything is refetched, and I only see posts from page 1 of course.
Which changes should I make to keep the index as it was when I go back to it?

You need to maintain the state of the list page, so when you return to it you can restore to the correct page number.   Search for "blazor state management" to see the different ways to do that,

Ok, I thought it could have been fixed with some kind of implicit browser caching or something with the component lifecycle. I have to implement the caching myself, Ok.

Yes, you have to implement the caching yourself.
